# scrollview scrolls smooth in simulator but not in device?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

i have page control sample from apple and using it in my application... in my application scrolling is running smooth in simulator but when installed on device it is not smooth.
does someone knows about it? i am also doing some flip animation.it's also not running smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it is running slower on the device (potentially several times slower) is completely normal. The simulator is not cycle accurate, it has access to all of the RAM, GPU resources, and processors on the host system.

Without actually knowing what you are doing no one can tell you how to improve performance, but there is nothing wrong with your app that is making it run slower and choppier on the device than in the sim that can be fixed to make it perform like it does in the simulator.